# how to deal with dependence/interaction among covariates in a cox regression model

Tags: regression, cox-model, independence

In case of a linear regression, if we are to account for interaction between two regressors x1 and x2, we write a model like 
    `lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x1:x2, data=records)`

Do we use a similar method/notation even in cox regression like
    `coxph(Surv(y,censor) ~ x1 + x2 + x1:x2, data=records)` ?

In other words, how does cox-regression deal with interaction/dependence among covariates?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by regressors being "related"? The `x1:x2` syntax examines an _interaction_ between `x1` and `x2` in terms of predicting y; that is, it examines whether the influence of `x1` depends on the value of `x2`. That's different from examining a _linear dependence_ between `x1` and `x2`. If `x1` and `x2` are highly linearly correlated so that they are close to measuring the same thing, one might expect no significant _interaction_ as judged by the `x1:x2` term in the regression.

Comment: @EdM modifed my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, interaction terms are specified in the same way for Cox regression as for linear regression. Interpretation of the interaction coefficients in Cox regression is probably best done in terms of the hazard ratios, shown in the `exp(coef)` values.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this page from Maartin Buis:
http://maartenbuis.nl/publications/interactions.html
A the end of the examples list is an example interpreting coefficients in a Cox model.
It uses Stata, not R, but the its the idea that counts.

His paper in the Stata Journal also brings up good points about interpreting interaction terms in non-linear models like this. Rather than sum it up, it's probably best if you read through his paper, its only 6 pages, but hits on a lot of good points.